# different behavior after Shell Shock patch when trying to execution bash function from find

Tags: bash

consider the following code:

```
#!/bin/env bash
function myfile { echo $* ; }
export -f myfile
find . -type l -exec bash -c 'myfile "{}"'  \;
```

pre Shell Shock patch I could execute the last 3 lines from the command line and it would work. Post Shell Shock I need to execute the code from a script.

If fact I can define the function from the command line and just put the find in a script and it will work.

if I do an env I can see the function listed, but the bash command on the find line won't see it.

any thoughts ?

Comment: **Which** shellshock patch you applied matters, and this question can't be answered without that information. Some of the early ones just disabled import of exported functions entirely.

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com might be a more productive place to ask this.

Comment: As a sidenote, your use of `{}` in `-exec` is wrong: it allows for arbitrary code execution. Use `find . -type l -exec bash -c 'myfile "$0"' {} \;` instead.

Comment: Would you provide an example of how?

Comment: @kdubs: Suppose you had a file named `;rm -rf .`, for example.

Comment: clever. I'll have to try that under a controled setting.

Comment: @kdubs, even if you can't reproduce with the exact code rici gave there, a more cleverly constructed malicious name _would_ allow breakout (take `./$(rm -rf /)/`, for instance). The solution given in by gniourf_gniourf is appropriate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy would you explain how the above syntax is safer? I can see you are trying to avoid the file name from being used as a command, but I'm failing to see exactly what you doing to prevent it.

Comment: @kdubs, an expansion (such as `"$0"`) doesn't have its post-expansion contents eval'd. If the expansion is unquoted, such contents are string-split and glob-expanded, if the expansion is within double quotes, the contents are treated as literals. By contrast, `"{}"` is having `find` perform literal text replacement **before** bash performs any initial parsing, so the substituted text can do... well, anything, including breaking back out of quotes. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser for additional background.

Comment: @kdubs, ...you might also read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- the failures it's inquiring about stem from the same semantic differences that make one of these approaches safe and the other not.

Comment: Hmm. My prior comment wasn't precise enough -- I could see future readers being confused by it, so I'm going to clarify: A bare `{}` argument to find is safe so long as it's not in a position where it's interpreted as code (only the argument directly after `bash -c` is seen as code, future arguments are literal data). By contrast, putting `"{}"` **within** the `-c` argument means that the expansion results are interpreted as part of the code. (Also, not all implementations of `find` will recognize `{}` as anything other than a bare argument).

Answer (score 1):

Check to see which bash your command-line sessions is using. It may be different from the `bash` which is invoked using a `$PATH` search. (i.e. by typing `bash` on the command-line, or by using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as a shebang line.)

If you have two bash executables, one shellshock-patched and the other one not, then you will not be able to export functions between the two.

You can tell which bash is executed by `bash -c` with the command `which bash`. To see which bash you use as your shell, grep your username in `/etc/passwd` and look at the last field.

Using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as a shebang line has its pros and cons. The fact that it does not explicitly show which bash is being invoked could be considered either an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on the circumstances :)

Comment: Did think of because I had it messed up at first. That doesn't seem to be the issue. I actually pass the full path to make sure

Comment: @kdubs. OK. The fact that it works in a script and not in your standard shell session does suggest that your standard shell session is using a different bash. It should be easy enough to check, if you are so inclined.

Comment: I'm checking into that. pretty sure it's the same, but I will verify.

Comment: okay. it's a mismatch of versions, but it's a mismatch of patched versions which is what through me off. I tried the 'echo vulnerable' trick, and assumed (incorrectly!) that since both bashes were patch, they'd work together. that is not the case here. thanks for making me verify that. now to figure out why my login bash doesn't match my PATH bash. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak to the why of it without knowing exactly which shellshock patch you applied (clearly, it wasn't the final official one -- *or* you're calling from a version of bash with one version of the patch into a different interpreter with an incompatible patch), but I can give you a workaround that doesn't rely on exported functions at all -- several workarounds, in fact.

One easy one is just to expand the definition of the function into your command passed to the subshell:

```
#!/bin/env bash
myfile() { echo $* ; }
find . -type l \
       -exec bash -c "$(declare -f myfile);"' for x; do myfile "$x"; done' _ '{}' +
```

Another one is to do the work in the parent shell, where no function is needed:

```
#!/bin/env bash
myfile() { echo $* ; }
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  myfile "$filename"
done < <(find . -type l -print0)
```

Comment: the first one is clever. might get a little slow for a big function, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: Heh. Looks like I called it correctly ("calling from a version of bash with one version of the patch into a different interpreter with an incompatible patch").

Comment: Edited to fix the safety issues raised by gniourf_gniourf, and also the performance issues raised in your comment (by taking more than one filename on the command line for each interpreter).